# Allowing a user to edit ONE view

Tags: views

I have a staff member that needs to be able to update a View in the drupal admin area...specifically they need to be able to change the node id displaying in a block.

Is there a way to allow this person to edit just this view?

And if that's not possible what permission do I need to give them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that that's possible as described, but you could do something like this:

- create a content type with only one field, accessible to the staff member
- add an [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to the content type housed in the view

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities

- create a relationship to the staff member content type

This would allow the Staff member to change the value in the content to which they have access, which would affect the View, but not directly have admin access to the View or the Admin sections of the Views UI

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a follow-up question. I added the ER module and created a new content type with a field 'resource_name' that references with an ER select list all the resources in the resource content type (my primary content type). Then in the View I added as a field this ER field but it just prints out the name of resource selected from that list and doesn't give the option to 'link to original content source' like a view field typically does. Suggestions on how to make that happen?

Comment: the relationship creates a link to the content, adding a field does not, then you can filter by the value of the fields in the related content